# Python win32com to forward a selected email with added content

Tags: python-2.7, email, outlook

Some time ago I wrote a simple python app which asks users for input and generates a new mail via Outlook app basing on the input. Now, I was asked to add some functionality so the app will no longer generate a new mail but it'll forward a selected email and add content to it. While I was able to write code which generates a new mail, I'm completely lost when I want to approach it with forwarding selected mails.

At the moment I use something like this to send a new email:

```py
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

const=win32com.client.constants
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = 'mail@mail.com'
newMail.Subject = ""
newMail.BodyFormat = 2
newMail.HTMLBody = output
newMail.To = ""
newMail.CC = ""
newMail.display()
```

And I know that by using something like this you can select an email in Outlook so Python can interact with it :

```py
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
selection = obj.ActiveExplorer().Selection
```

How to merge these two together so the app will forward a selected email and add a new content on the top? I tried to find it out by trial and error, but finally, I gave up. Microsoft API documentation also was not very helpful for me as I was not really able to understand much of it (I'm not a dev). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line `newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)` with

```
newMail = obj.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Forward()
```